# Groovy Cast primitive type

Tags: groovy, casting, primitive

I want to set fields dynamically in groovy so I have a java code that get datas from a database and I set groovy fields using `Bindings.setVariable()` in java.

I would like to know if it is possible to cast each primitive types in groovy.
`String` to `int`, `String` to `float` and so on.
So I could always send a string and cast in an other primitive times, it depends of the type of my groovy fields.

Answer (score 4):

@Opal's `as` solution is good, but I also wanted to mention that the Groovy JDK adds some convenient primitive check and conversion methods to [CharSequence](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html), which String implements:

- `isDouble` and `asDobule`
- `isFloat` and `asFloat`
- `isLong` and `asLong`
- `isInteger` and `asInteger`

Interestingly, it `isFloat` seems to be greedy, returning `true` for floating points beyond its range.

```
['2', '2.2', '2' * 10, "${Double.MAX_VALUE}"].each { s ->
    switch (s) {
        case { it.isInteger() }:
            int i = s.toInteger()
            println "String '$s' -> int $i"
            break  
        case { it.isLong() }:
            long l = s.toLong()
            println "String '$s' -> long $l"
            break
        case { it.isFloat() }:
            float f = s.toFloat()
            println "String '$s' -> float $f"
            break             
        case { it.isDouble() }:
            double d = s.toDouble()
            println "String '$s' -> double $d"
            break     
        default:
            println "$s is not a supported primitive"
    }
}
```

prints out

```
String '2' -> int 2
String '2.2' -> float 2.2
String '2222222222' -> long 2222222222
String '1.7976931348623157E308' -> float Infinity
```

Comment: I would use `switch ( s.toString() )` to be on the safer side because `is*()` is only applied to `String`. Having a `Number` or `null` in the above list by chance would fail the checks.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you exactly need, but the following piece of code works well:

```
assert '2' as Integer == 2
assert '2.2' as Double == 2.2
```

Comment: @SteevenBrunner, if that's what you needed, please accept the answer.